# How to clean up temporary file used with send_file?

Tags: python, flask, web-frameworks

I'm currently developing a server side json interface where several temporary files are manipulating during requests.

My current solution for cleaning up these files at the end of the request looks like this:

```
@app.route("/method",methods=['POST'])
def api_entry():
    with ObjectThatCreatesTemporaryFiles() as object:
        object.createTemporaryFiles()
        return "blabalbal"
```

In this case, the cleanup takes lace in object.__exit__()

However in a few cases I need to return a temporary files to the client, in which case the code looks like this:

```
@app.route("/method",methods=['POST'])
def api_entry():
    with ObjectThatCreatesTemporaryFiles() as object:
        object.createTemporaryFiles()
        return send_file(object.somePath)
```

This currently does not work, because when I the cleanup takes place flask is in the process of reading the file and sending it to the client.
¨
How can I solve this?

Edit: I Forgot to mention that the files are located in temporary directories.

Answer (score 14):

The method I've used is to use weak-references to delete the file once the response has been completed.

```
import shutil
import tempfile
import weakref

class FileRemover(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.weak_references = dict()  # weak_ref -> filepath to remove

    def cleanup_once_done(self, response, filepath):
        wr = weakref.ref(response, self._do_cleanup)
        self.weak_references[wr] = filepath

    def _do_cleanup(self, wr):
        filepath = self.weak_references[wr]
        print('Deleting %s' % filepath)
        shutil.rmtree(filepath, ignore_errors=True)

file_remover = FileRemover()
```

And in the flask call I had:

```
@app.route('/method')
def get_some_data_as_a_file():
    tempdir = tempfile.mkdtemp()
    filepath = make_the_data(dir_to_put_file_in=tempdir)
    resp = send_file(filepath)
    file_remover.cleanup_once_done(resp, tempdir)
    return resp
```

This is quite general and as an approach has worked across three different python web frameworks that I've used.

Comment: This solution was helpful. I have a situation where three files are created by my code. If a user chooses to download one file, the others are deleted. The selected file remains, but I think that's because I'm in a Windows environment. Thanks for this.

Comment: It works, and the core function is base on `weakref`, for whom not familiar with `weakref` https://docs.python.org/3/library/weakref.html has some explaination.

Comment: just `resp = send_file(filepath)` then `os.reomve(filepath)` and `return resp` this 3 lines were enough I didn't need to use FileRemover class or anything else! Thanks

Comment: @PekoChan That will work on Linux and (probably) Mac OS, but not on Windows. On Linux you can delete a file that is open. On Windows you cannot.

Comment: Works like a charm!

Comment: I have tried this on Windows 2021 - 07 -01 and it doesn't work. It gives me permission error because the file es being used by flask, due to the fact that he has put ignore_errors = True, no exception will be thrown if rmtree fails to delete the file/dir

Comment: @Ángel I've been noticing shutil.rmtree failing on recent versions of windows in other situations over the last few years. Removing the ignore_errors, and retrying a few times on failure seems to solve it. That would probably work in this case too.

Comment: @RasjidWilcox I would rather prefer doing this fine at first, see my last post, I think is the only way that is compatible in all systems. But has a trade off because the file has to be in memory

Answer (score 11):

If you are using Flask 0.9 or greater you can use the [`after_this_request`](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/api/#flask.after_this_request) decorator:

```
@app.route("/method",methods=['POST'])
def api_entry():
    tempcreator = ObjectThatCreatesTemporaryFiles():
    tempcreator.createTemporaryFiles()

    @after_this_request
    def cleanup(response):
        tempcreator.__exit__()
        return response

    return send_file(tempcreator.somePath)
```

**EDIT**

Since that doesn't work, you could try using [`cStringIO`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stringio.html#module-cStringIO) instead (this assumes that your files are small enough to fit in memory):

```
@app.route("/method", methods=["POST"])
def api_entry():
    file_data = dataObject.createFileData()
    # Simplest `createFileData` method:  
    # return cStringIO.StringIO("some\ndata")
    return send_file(file_data,
                        as_attachment=True,
                        mimetype="text/plain",
                        attachment_filename="somefile.txt")
```

Alternately, you could create the temporary files as you do now, but *not* depend on your application to delete them.  Instead, set up a cron job (or a Scheduled Task if you are running on Windows) to run every hour or so and delete files in your temporary directory that were created more than half an hour before.

Comment: My answer feels like a dirty hack next to this one.

Comment: Unfortunetely it appears that flask still has the file opened at the time that @after_this_request is called :(

Comment: @monoceres :-(  That is to bad - I've updated my answer with some additional suggestions.

Answer (score 3):

I have two solutions.

---

The first solution is to delete the file in the `__exit__` method, but not close it. That way, the file-object is still accessible, and you can pass it to `send_file`.

This will only work if you do not use `X-Sendfile`, because it uses the filename.

---

The second solution is to rely on the garbage collector. You can pass to `send_file` a file-object that will clean the file on deletion (`__del__` method). That way, the file is only deleted when the file-object is deleted from python. You can use [`TemporaryFile`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/tempfile.html#tempfile.TemporaryFile) for that, if you don't already.

Comment: Interesting, I will review these options, also see my edit concerning directories.

Comment: The first solution still works, because it is based on the fact that (on linux at least) opened file can still be read after the file is removed (unlinked). The second won't if the object that does the cleanup is the file-object.

Answer (score 3):

It's a bit late, but this is what I did using [madjar's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/981855/madjar) suggestions (in case anyone else comes across this). This is a little helper function that I use (it takes a PyExcelerate Workbook object as parameter) which you could adapt to your case. Just change the way you create/build your tempfile.TemporaryFile and you're set! Tested on Windows 8.1 and Ubuntu 12.04.

```
def xlsx_to_response(wb, filename):
    f = tempfile.TemporaryFile()
    wb._save(f)
    f.seek(0)
    response = send_file(f, as_attachment=True, attachment_filename=filename,
                         add_etags=False)

    f.seek(0, os.SEEK_END)
    size = f.tell()
    f.seek(0)
    response.headers.extend({
        'Content-Length': size,
        'Cache-Control': 'no-cache'
    })
    return response
```

Comment: Thanks a ton for this. I had done everything I could, but it wasn't working.
When I saw your answer, I realized I had forgotten f.seek(0)

Answer (score 2):

We can use `tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile()` which automatically deletes the file when `send_file()` closes it.

```
temp_csv_file = tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(mode='w', encoding='utf-8', delete=True)
csv_writer = csv.writer(temp_csv_file)
csv_writer.writerow(["Name", "Age"])
for age in range(1,10):
    csv_writer.writerow(["alice", age])
return send_file(
    path_or_file=temp_csv_file.name,
    mimetype='text/csv',
    as_attachment=True,
    download_name='downloaded.csv'
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

### Windows / Linux / Mac compatible solution

I have tried weakrefs, flask built-in decorators and nothing worked.

The only think that worked in every system is to create a temporal file in memory using io.BytesIO

```
import os
import io
import tempfile
from multiprocessing import Process

import flask


def background_job(callback):
    task = Process(target=callback())
    task.start()

def send_temp_file(file_path: str, temp_dir: tempfile.TemporaryDirectory, remove_dir_after_send=True):
    with open(file_path, "rb") as f:
        content = io.BytesIO(f.read())
    response = flask.send_file(content,
                               as_attachment=True,
                               attachment_filename=os.path.split(file_path)[0])
    if remove_dir_after_send:
        background_job(temp_dir.cleanup)
    return response



app = flask.Flask(__name__)


@app.route("/serve_file/", methods=["GET"])
def serve_file():
    temp_dir = tempfile.TemporaryDirectory()
    file_path = os.path.join(temp_dir.name, "test.txt")
    with open(file_path, "w") as f:
        f.write("Hello World!")

    return send_temp_file(file_path, temp_dir)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(port=1337)
```