# How can I generate file on the fly and delete it after download?

Tags: python, flask

here's my function that creates file on the fly(when the user clicks proper link)

```
@app.route('/survey/<survey_id>/report')
def survey_downloadreport(survey_id):
    survey, bsonobj = survey_get(survey_id) #get object
    resps = response_get_multi(survey_id) #get responses to the object

    fields = ["_id", "sid", "date", "user_ip"] #meta-fields
    fields.extend(survey.formfields) #survey-specific fields

    randname = "".join(random.sample(string.letters + string.digits, 15)) + ".csv" #some random file name

    with open("static//" + randname, "wb") as csvf:
        wr = csv.DictWriter(csvf, fields, encoding = 'cp949')
        wr.writerow(dict(zip(fields, fields))) #dummy, to explain what each column means
        for resp in resps :
            wr.writerow(resp)

    return send_from_directory("static", randname, as_attachment = True)
```

I'd like to have file to be deleted after completing of the download. How can I do it?

Comment: send_from_directory come from a library or is written by you?

Comment: that is from flask api. http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/api/#flask.send_from_directory

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13344538/how-to-clean-up-temporary-file-used-with-send-file

Answer (score 7):

On Linux, if you have an open file you can still read it even when deleted. Do this:

```
import tempfile
from flask import send_file

csvf = tempfile.TemporaryFile()
wr = csv.DictWriter(csvf, fields, encoding = 'cp949')
wr.writerow(dict(zip(fields, fields))) #dummy, to explain what each column means
for resp in resps :
    wr.writerow(resp)
wr.close()
csvf.seek(0)  # rewind to the start

send_file(csvf, as_attachment=True, attachment_filename='survey.csv')
```

The `csvf` file is deleted as soon as it is created; the OS will reclaim the space once the file is closed (which cpython will do for you as soon as the request is completed and the last reference to the file object is deleted). Optionally, you could use the [`after_this_request` hook](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13345241) to explicitly close the file object.

Comment: This feature gave us a hard time some time ago. Our mailserver was unlinking files without closing the file descriptors. Suddenly the system reported `disk full` but `df` was showing plenty of disk space. Use with caution - it can be really hard to find such bug.

Comment: @bikeshedder: check for open file descriptors next time :-) It's a common enough pattern.

Comment: To the suggested edit: note the `attachment_filename` argument used for `send_file()`; it provides the filename to be used, not the temporary file. There is absolutely no need to use a `NamedTemporaryFile` here.

Comment: @Martijn Pieters How do I check for open file descriptors next time?

Answer (score -1):

I've used os.unlink for a while with success:

```
import os

os.unlink(os.path.join('/path/files/csv/', '%s' % file))
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: The `'%s' % file` is redundant; at most, use `str(file)` if `file` is not already a string.