# Returning a Numpy Array as a CSV from Flask

Tags: python, numpy, flask, export-to-csv

I have part of an API in Flask that currently returns a Numpy array in Json, I need to offer the option to return as a CSV rather than as Json.

The only way I have successfully done this is to save the Numpy array as a CSV using numpy.savetxt then serve that file.  I have found I can not leave the file behind like this [How can I generate file on the fly and delete it after download?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14614756/how-can-i-generate-file-on-the-fly-and-delete-it-after-download/14614943#14614943) however that still feels 'kludgy'

Is there a way to return a Numpy array as a CSV without going via the file?

Comment: What datatype is in your numpy array, and is it an ndarray or just a 1darray?

Comment: types - typically np.float16.  They are ndarrays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, if you want to use the numpy.savetxt function, then you can just use cStringIO:

```
from cStringIO import StringIO
output = StringIO()
numpy.savetxt(output, numpy_array)
csv_string = output.getvalue()
```

For python 3 you would import StringIO or BytesIO from the io module instead.

Comment: This looks exactly like what I need.  Will try and report back.

Comment: This allowed me to create the CSV using savetxt and serve as required without going via a CSV.  Thx!

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can,

```
@app.route('/download')
def download():
    csv = convert_numpy_array_to_csv(your_numpy_array)
    response = make_response(csv)
    response.headers["Content-Disposition"] = "attachment; filename=array.csv"
    return response
```

You don't have to save the csv to a file. In case you can't avoid creating files, you can create the files in your temp folders (could be obtained by `import tempfile;tempfile.gettempdir()`). Doing so would automatically remove the files every time your system is restarted

Comment: Thanks for the answer - however the way I go from Numpy to csv (numpy.writetxt) only exports to a file.

Comment: Thanks - I was using tempfile but didn't want to leave the files hanging around between reboots.