# Delete temporary folder after returning using send_file() of flask python on Windows Server

Tags: python, flask, flask-restful

I am trying to delete a temporary folder where I save an image and do some processing on it and then return some results. I used `shutil.rmtree(filepath)` and it works correctly on Mac OS. However when I run it on Windows server, it fails with an error saying file is still in use.

I referred this question on stack overflow [How to clean up temporary file used with send_file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13344538/how-to-clean-up-temporary-file-used-with-send-file)

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32132035/5928128) using weak references helps in removing the error that was thrown on Windows, but the folder is still not deleted. Though it still works correctly on Mac OS.

How can I delete the temporary folder after the request has been completed on Windows system?

Here is my code snippet for your reference.

```
    def post(self):
    try:
        if 'photo' not in request.files:
            raise NoFilesError
        file = request.files['photo']
        print('file = ', file)
        if file.filename == '':
            raise NoFilesError
        if file and self._allowed_file(file.filename):
            filename = secure_filename(file.filename)
            dir_path = os.path.join(BaseAPIConfig.UPLOAD_FOLDER, get_timestamp())
            create_directory(dir_path)
            file_path = os.path.join(dir_path, filename)
            file.save(file_path)
            img_proc_main(dir_path, filename)
            image_filename = filename.rsplit('.', 1)[0]
            image_format = filename.rsplit('.', 1)[1]
            result_file = os.path.join(dir_path, image_filename + '_bb.' + image_format)
            response = make_response(send_file(result_file))
            file_remover = FileRemover()
            file_remover.cleanup_once_done(response, dir_path)
            return response
            ...
```

FileRemover class

```
class FileRemover(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.weak_references = dict()  # weak_ref -> filepath to remove

    def cleanup_once_done(self, response, filepath):
        wr = weakref.ref(response, self._do_cleanup)
        self.weak_references[wr] = filepath

    def _do_cleanup(self, wr):
        filepath = self.weak_references[wr]
        print('Deleting %s' % filepath)
        shutil.rmtree(filepath, ignore_errors=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using `ignore_errors=True`, which hides away any exception that `shutil.rmtree` encounters.

There are many reasons why `shutil.rmtree` might fail to remove the directory—perhaps you simply don't have the correct permission on Windows. Setting `ignore_errors` to false will give you more indications of what's going on.

Comment: Exception ignored in: <bound method FileRemover._do_cleanup of <app.utils.file_utils.FileRemover object at 0x0000023F7AF768E0>>
PermissionError: [WinError 32] The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process: 'D:\\bb_upload_folder\\1589722538\\R_15_1_bb.jpeg'

This is the exception thrown when set ignore_errors=False

Comment: In that case you need to close the file or kill the process that has it open first