# Deleting images after serving them in Flask

Tags: python, flask

I have a flask app which seeks to fetch images from an API and serve them to the user.

Currently, the app works by fetching an image, saving it to `/static/images/image_xx.jpg`, then creating the relevant view with

```
render_template(
            myview.html,
            image_path=f"/static/images/image_xx.jpg")
```

I'd like to get rid of the image data after serving it. So far I've been doing it by simply looping purging any images in `/static/images` **before** I make the request and save the image to serve. However that's causing concurrency issues, and when traffic is high some users images get deleted before being served.

Is there a better way of doing this? Thanks!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32132035/4466467 might help. Use a tempfile with send_file

Comment: Stupid question but I can't figure it out from the thread or docs: how do I use send_file to render my image on the template?